# Emacs 24.3: Hide/ignore "'unibyte: t' is obsolete" warnings?

Tags: emacs, emacs24

I use a fair number of 3rd-party packages, and when I start emacs I get a long list of warnings in the `*Warnings*` buffer (which shows automatically) with the line:

```
Warning (mule): `unibyte: t' is obsolete; use "coding: 'raw-text" instead.
```

While I don't close emacs often, it's getting rather annoying when I make changes to and then reload my emacs config.

Any way I can kill/hide/tell emacs to ignore this particular error?

Comment: this could help for some warning tuning, but I don't know if obsolete warning can be silenced through this http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Warning-Options.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
(setq warning-suppress-types '('(mule))
```

That will block all warnings with type `mule` but I think the warning you see is the only one Mule ever generates.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can find & replace `unibyte: t` into `coding: raw-text`.

I just search them by runing: `grep -Rl 'unibyte: t' ~/.emacs.d`,
and findout it is in file `plugins/goto-last-change.el` line 1, then I update it.
After that, it works fine.